# Sql Verify username from database = username login

Tags: php, sql, session, request

I need to verify if the client connected = client in sql database

first I connect to my database

```
    try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cruel', 'root', '');
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

After I get my login user :

```
session_start() ;
$usrUserName = $_SESSION['usrUserName'];
```

I'm making my sql request :

```
$requete = $bdd->prepare('SELECT `timId`,`usrId`, `usrUserName`,`timUserId`,`timVerified`,`prtTimeSheetid`
FROM  `timesheets` ,  `users` ,  `projetstaches` 
WHERE  `prtTimeSheetId` = ( 
SELECT MAX(  `prtTimeSheetId` ) 
FROM projetstaches ) 
AND  `prtTimeSheetId` =  `timID` AND `timUserId`= `UsrId` AND usrUserName =:usrUserName');
    $requete->execute(array('timVerified'=> 'timVerified')) or die(print_r($requete->errorInfo()));
    $resultat = $requete->fetch();
    $timVerified = $resultat['timVerified'];    
    echo($timVerified);
    echo($usrUserName);
```

But Where AND usrUserName =:usrUserName'); (I know It is there the problem cause when I remove its echo perfectly but I need to check if my username login is = my username databse ) give me this error :

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www\testlp\modifiersheet.php on line 18
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `$requete->execute(array(':usrUserName'=> $usrUserName))` not `$requete->execute(array('timVerified'=> 'timVerified'))`

Comment: Add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, to find the real problems.

Comment: you have not passed your parameter $usrUserName to the $requete

Comment: OH right thought that would need the timVerified in the requete execute array.